# How to get physical coordinates

Tags: android

I have drawn a map in OpenGL. What I want is whenever user touches the screen I should get coordinates relative to OpenGL maps not just screen coordinates.

Following is my piece of code which I have tried but I am not getting correct coordinates:

```
// Initialize auxiliary variables.
PointF worldPos = new PointF();

// Auxiliary matrix and vectors
// to deal with ogl.
float[] invertedMatrix, transformMatrix,
        normalizedInPoint, outPoint;
invertedMatrix = new float[16];
transformMatrix = new float[16];
normalizedInPoint = new float[4];
outPoint = new float[4];

// Invert y coordinate, as android uses
// top-left, and ogl bottom-left.
int oglTouchY = (int) (scrheigth - touch.Y);

/* Transform the screen point to clip
space in ogl (-1,1) */
normalizedInPoint[0] =
        (float) ((touch.X) * 2.0f / scrwidth - 1.0);
normalizedInPoint[1] =
        (float) ((oglTouchY) * 2.0f / scrheigth - 1.0);
normalizedInPoint[2] = - 1.0f;
normalizedInPoint[3] = 1.0f;

/* Obtain the transform matrix and
then the inverse. */

Matrix.multiplyMM(
        transformMatrix, 0,
        mProjMatrix, 0,
        mMVPMatrix, 0);
Matrix.invertM(invertedMatrix, 0,
        transformMatrix, 0);

/* Apply the inverse to the point
in clip space */
Matrix.multiplyMV(
        outPoint, 0,
        invertedMatrix, 0,
        normalizedInPoint, 0);

if (outPoint[3] == 0.0)
{
    // Avoid /0 error.
    Log.e("World coords", "ERROR!");
    return worldPos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for view override onTouch method. Then for MotionEvent object use getX() and getY() methods

Comment: sir actually what i want is to get absolute position of touch point of map drawn by openGL

Answer (score 0):

The motion event dispatched to your view always uses the relative position in its parent view. You might need to recursively add the parent view's coordination to get the absolute position on screen.

Comment: sir actually what i want is to get absolute position of touch point of map drawn by openGL